# System.InvalidOperationException: Ошибка при создании документа XML

Tags: c#, xml, веб-программирование, веб-служба

Здравствуйте, есть веб-сервис для доступа к БД, при попытке запустить метод `LogPas()` выдает ошибку

> System.InvalidOperationException: Ошибка при создании документа XML. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Невозможно сериализовать System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal, т.*к. он не имеет беспараметрического конструктора.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public ArrayList LogPas()
    {
        ArrayList allData = new ArrayList();  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM Student", con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            { foreach (DbDataRecord result in dr)         
                        allData.Add(result);

            return allData;
            }
        else return null;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам компилятор и так всё сказал. Передать объект с типом DataRecordInternal не получится, так как для сериализации требуется конструктор без параметров, коего нет у данного типа.
Самое простое решение - использовать другой класс.

Comment: например, какой?

Comment: А это уже от Вас зависит, хоть вот так:

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }

Понятное дело, сначала придётся заполнить поля.

Comment: Извините, но я не совсем поняла. Создать класс для чего?

Comment: Вам так или иначе придётся использовать класс, который возможно сериализовать, чтобы вернуть его из сервиса. Если хотите, делайте свой класс и заполняйте, либо же можно, например, заполнить DataSet и его передать.

Comment: Если заполнять DataSet результатом, то воспользуйтесь SqlDataAdapter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, все получилось:)

Comment: Не за что. Не забывайте отмечать вопрос как решённый.